# I want to block a iam-test-user from production-ec2instance

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I want to block a iam-test-user from production-ec2instance with ec2 tag.

I think IAM policy have implicit deny.

So I added tag "Purpose/Test" to test-ec2instance.

And I applied a iam-policy-file below to iam-test-user.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"ec2:ResourceTag/Purpose": "Test"}}
    }
] }
```

But iam-test-user can't see all ec2instance include test-ec2instance on aws-console.

Is the json file wrong?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "block user from instance". What are you wanting to "block"? I think you're saying that you don't want them to be able to see that instances when they view a list of all EC2 instances in the region. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a English begginer. I want to deny iam-test-user all operation of production instance. And I want to allow him all operation of test instance. Does my answer make sense?

Comment: Thank you, I understand. However, what do you mean by "allow him all operation of test instance"? An IAM policy can grant permissions to Start, Stop, Terminate and Modify an instance. However, it does not control the ability to login to an instance and 'use' the instance. Also, it is not possible to control what instances are listed in a `describe-instances` call. Thus, I am trying to understand better what you are wanting to Grant. Can you please provide more information? For example, what problem are you experiencing when using the above policy?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late and thank you for your kindness. All operation means controllable in IAM policy. It's not covered login. It's difficult to explain in English...

Answer (score 0):

Your policy is saying:

- Allow this entity to do anything (`ec2:*`) on EC2...
- If the resource has a tag of `Purpose:Test`

This should work when starting and stopping an instance with that tag.

Then you say: *can't see all ec2instance include test-ec2instance on aws-console*

The API call that returns a list of instances is `DescribeInstances`. This command is *NOT* related to a single instance, so it is unable to use tags. Therefore, the command will *not* function.

While you might think that you are assigning permissions so that they can **only list Test instances**, the command that lists instances does not look at the tags on the instances themselves. It just lists instances.

Here is an example:

- I only give you permission to talk to anyone who has a name of 'Keisuke'
- I then ask you to count how many people are standing in a room

The *room* does not have a name of Keisuke, so you cannot count the number of people in the room.

Similarly, it is not possible to limit the instances returned from a `DescribeInstances` command. You either give entities permissions to list the *all*, or list *none*.